# Cross-domain issue with Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cross-domain

I am trying to create a chrome extension which will look up the meaning of input vocabulary from this URL: http://hanviet.org/ajax.php?query=%E6%97%A5&methode=normal

I made an ajax call by using jquery but got an error because of the cross-domain issue: *"No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access"*. Ok, I guest that instead of make a request directly to the URL, I need to call it through a proxy pages as below:

```
$.get("/myproxy.php?query=日&methode=normal", function( data ) {
    alert( "Load was performed." );
});
```

After doing a google search, there is another chrome extension named DHC to makes http request: https://www.sprintapi.com/dhcs.html. and It works perfectly!

I am wondering that does DHC tool also send a request through its proxy or there is another way to make a direct request that I dont know.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the developers tools of chrome on that site, on Network tab you will see that after pressing the `send`button it loads the content from `https://www.sprintapi.com/api/proxy`, so yes, it should be using a proxy.

Even more, as you say the *Access-Control-Allow-Origin* would'nt let they did it on another way I think.

Answer (score 3):

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'URL',
        jsonp: 'callback',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        data: {},
        success: loginSuccess,
        crossDomain: true,
        error: ajaxFailed,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        async: false
    });

    function ajaxFailed(result) {
        alert("Failed: " + result.status + ' ' + result.statusText);
    }

    function loginSuccess(data) {
        alert('Result: ' + data.d);
    }
```

Comment: Not sure if this code works! I made a request using the above code and it went to "Failed: 200 load" message.